# Calculating sound waves from a local compression

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

Let us say that we have a well-behaved fluid in all space (with speed of sound $c_0$ and density $\rho_0$). And I manage to compress it such that the pressure $p(\vec{r},t)$ at $t=0$ is given by

$p(\vec{r},t=0) = A \exp( -|\vec{r}|^2 / \sigma^2 ) + p_0$.

If we now let the system evolve freely, how can I calculate the sound wave at a different location. That is, how can I calculate $p(\vec{r}, t>0)?$

Please help me out, I assume I have to solve for the wave PDE, but I do not really know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no sources or sinks (like absorbers), then the wave evolution in essentially "in vacuo". The governing equation (in 1D) is [hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave_equation#In_one_dimension):

$$ \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2} = 0,$$

which has an "analytical" solution given by:
$$ p = f(ct-x) + g(ct+x), $$
where $f$ and $g$ are two (differentiable) functions representing right- and left-moving solutions.

Let us set $A = c = \sigma = 1$.

Choosing $f = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{(x-t)^2}$ and $g = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{(x+t)^2}$, and propagating in time, I get:
[image]

I can also numerically solve the PDE above by "brute force" and imposing your initial condition $p(x,t=0) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$, and get the same thing as above:

[image]

Comment: Super, thanks.. but how can I solve this for the 3D case?

Comment: .... same thing, just use the 3D wave equation.